# Nginx redirects http to https for subdomain, but shows top level domain

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to work as following:
Top-level domain, say example.com, being accessed by HTTP, redirects to HTTPS. All its subdomains must also redirect to HTTPS (obviously, subdomain must redirect to itself, but HTTPS).

Here is the configuration (file `default`):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com *.example.com;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        root /home/user/wwwroot;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Here is the configuration for the 'yt' subdomain (file `yt`)

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name yt.example.com;

   location ^~ /.well-known {
      allow all;
      root /home/user/wwwroot;
   }

   location / {
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
   }

}
```

As one can see, yt.example.com just passes the request to an application (Youtrack in this case).

Redirect for example.com and www.example.com works fine, but for yt.example.com it behaves strangely. When I access http://yt.example.com, nginx redirects to https://yt.example.com, but serves content `root /home/user/wwwroot` specified at the `default` file. When I hit the refresh button, my browser reloads the page at https://yt.example.com and then nginx passes the request to the application as I've expected. So when it redirects HTTP to HTTPS it does not pass the request, but when the request is already using HTTPS it successfully redirects.

I'm not an nginx-guru, so I need some help.

Comment: maybe ipv6 issue. Try it without `listen [::]:443 ....`.

Comment: No luck unfortunately, disabling IPv6 does not solve the issue.

Comment: open browser's F12->network tab. We need real request IP and the Host header when the problem occurs. Get sure, it is not cached buggy 301 redirect.